# Solidity 0.5.x - make address array payable

Tags: addresses, arrays, payable, solidity

I'm trying to write a contract that uses an `address[]` array which should contain payable addresses. But apparently creating a payable address array doesn't work in solidity 0.5.x.

All I'm trying to do is to run a loop that transfers funds to each address in the array like this:

```
address[] users;
// set users
...
for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
  users[i].transfer(<some_value>);
}
```

My **super dumb** solution would be to use a proxy mapping to get a payable address. It would look like this and does actually compile.

```
address[] users;
mapping(address => address payable) proxy;
// set users and proxy
...
for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
   address payable u = proxy[users[i]];
   u.transfer(<some_value>);
}
```

Obviously this is pretty dumb. Is there a way to make an address array payable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Oh boy I'm stupid. `address payable[] users` works. Nevermind people. This question never happened...

Comment: I was here to check if it's `address[] payable` or `address payable[]`. You confirmed it, so thanks.

Comment: I love these answers where the asker answers himself...and also apparently me in the future lol